# Why can the adverb "otherwise" be used followed by a verb as an object in the sentence "But the research suggests otherwise"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adverbs, direct-objects

In the sentence

> But the research suggests otherwise,

we know "suggest" is a transitive verb, so my question is, what "otherwise" is then? I guess it's an adverb here, but we must use suggest + noun/v-ing or that clause as an object right?

If "otherwise" here is used as an adverb, does that means "suggest" can be used as an intransitive verb? Or an adverb can be used as an object? I don't think so, thus I'm really confused.

If "otherwise" here is **not** used as an adverb here, then what is the component of "suggest" in the sentence?

The complete sentence is:

> ‘It might be what we find interesting about this story is that it’s got this survival-relevant information in it,’ says anthropologist Jamie Tehrani at Durham University in the UK. **But his research suggests otherwise**. ‘We have this huge gap in our knowledge about the history and prehistory of storytelling, despite the fact that we know this genre is an incredibly ancient one,’ he says.

Comment: "Suggest" can be either transitive or intransitive depending on its complement.

Comment: Importantly, it functions as a pro-clause anaphor where the antecedent would be mentioned elsewhere in the discourse.

Comment: The question title doesn't make sense, it asks about "otherwise" followed by a verb, but then the example has "otherwise" at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ***Adverb*** [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/otherwise) gives this definition of *otherwise*

> You use *otherwise* to refer in a general way to actions or situations that are very different from, or the opposite to, your main statement.
> [written]
>
> - Take approximately 60mg up to four times a day, unless *advised **otherwise*** by a doctor.
> - I wanted this to be my wedding song, but was *convinced **otherwise***.

It is used as an adverb. You can replace it by ***differently*** or ***in a different way***. The direct objects of the verbs *advised, convinced or suggested* are implied. They will be something different or opposite from what was mentioned before.

It is true that the direct object must be expressed in a sentence with a transitive verb, ***except*** when it is so obvious, that it will be understood even if it is absent. In some cases, the sentence will be more successful if it is left unsaid, as it avoids unnecessary repetition. An example of this would be what [Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-direct-object-1690459) quotes from *Gail Brenner, Webster's New World American Idioms Handbook. Wiley, 2003*:

> Some transitive phrasal verbs do not use their direct object ***when the direct object is implied*** in the meaning of the idiom. For example, with the phrasal verb *pull over* (to move a vehicle out of the flow of traffic, and slow down or stop), it's not necessary to say
>
> > I pulled the car over
>
> because the car is implied by the idiom. You can simply say
>
> > I pulled over.

In your case, let's say that someone says **A**, *but the research suggests* ***B, C, D*** etc. which are *different* from A. This is expressed by the adverb *otherwise*. You can read this statement as:

> But his research suggests otherwise *[that...]*.

The sentence following, expresses what his research suggests.

Comment: Thanks! So you mean the object is omitted? And the complete sentence is "But the research suggests (it) otherwise"?

Comment: And if so, can you give a bit more details/information about when can I omit the object for transitive verbs because it sounds a little strange to me :)

Comment: "But the research suggests _the opposite/that this is not true_"

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I need to take some time to understand. Because in my original views, this breaks the rule "transitive verbs muse be used with a noun/v-ing or that clause **rather than an adverb**  as its object"

Comment: Thanks, I edit the question and add the complete sentence